# How to detect ips using nmap?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nmap, man-in-the-middle, local-network

I am currently working on demonstrating Man in middle Attack foe which I am using my phone as a Victim and my PC running ubuntu 14.04LTS as attacker. I am using nmap to ping my phone to check if its online...

```
nmap -e wlan0 -sn 172.16.95.198
```

But don't know how even when phones on same network I get a result ..

```
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.54 seconds
```

So I tried with -Pn as well but output remains the same (host seems down) which is not the case. The phone is up and running... Please help I am new to networking what am I possibly doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

The parameter -Pn is only for skip the host discovery. Probably Your phone has not any port listening. If you want to check if your phone has listening port:
In the phone:

```
netstat -lntu
```

If your phone has not any listening port, try to install one service and scan again.

Comment: This happens with any other device instead of phone too.

Comment: Yes, It is because the devices are dropping the ICMP packets

Comment: So what commands do you suggest in nmap so that i can detect ip's of various devices around on the same local network...

Comment: For example, you can use the parameter -PR (ARP Ping). Here you can see more methods to do a host discovery. http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html